# fatal error C1083 during build of program to test CStrings

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to explore the `CString` Data type which is used extensively in my company's test program.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <afx.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CString cs("meow");
    wcout << cs << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles with 0 errors. However, when I try to build it, I get the following error.

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlstr': No such file or directory
```

I am using Visual C++ 6 Standard Edition for development.

Please note that my company's test program can compile and run well and I don't get the aforementioned error.

Is there a place where I can download the `atlstr` include file?

Comment: Visual C++ 6, a.k.a. Visual Studio 98 predates even the first C++ standard. Why are you using such a dinosaur? That said, you claim your snippet compiles but then you quote a compiler error. That doesn't make sense! Maybe it is some unrelated error in combination with precompiled headers? Move to the commandline and compile your code there, there's a vcvars32.bat file which sets up the environment for building from the commandline to help you with that.

Comment: thanks for your input

Comment: _"The above code compiles with 0 errors. However, when I try to build it, I get the following error."_ That doesn't make any sense. How can it be compiled before you built it? Part of building it _is_ compiling it.